# Insert an element in the middle of a linked list, in a ordered way?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I got my linked list:

```
typedef struct t_node {
    ELEMLIST data;
    struct t_node *next;
} NODE;

typedef NODE *LIST;
```

And I try to insert the integer in an ordered way (from smaller to bigger numbers), but seems like something's not working:

```
STATUS insertInOrderList(LIST *list, const ELEMLIST *pElem) {

    NODE *newNode, *nodeIns;

    newNode = getNode();//allocate memory
    nodeIns = getNode();

   //checkout getnode return

    newNode->data = *pElem;

    for (nodeIns = *list; nodeIns != NULL; nodeIns = nodeIns->next) {
        if (cmpEleList(&newNode->data, &nodeIns->data) != 1) { 
             //if arg1 is not > arg2 it breaks the loop
            break;
        }
    }

    newNode->next = nodeIns;
    nodeIns->next = newNode;

    return OK;
}
```

When I run it it just tell me that my list is empty...

I'm sure it's just some detail I missed, but I just can't realize what

Comment: `nodoIns` or `nodeIns` ?

Comment: Unrelated: For all that is good in this world (and it ain't much), **please** don't hide pointers in typedefs unless (a) you're writing an API and abstracting a "handle" type, or (b) you're declaring a function-pointer-type. This is C. *Embrace the asterisks* and whisper sweet nothings to them. They deserve a seat in the front row.

Comment: edited, anyway it wasn't the problem

Comment: Oh I know it wasn't. but it makes it a bear for people your *asking* to review this. no worries, just a (strong) suggestion. Anyway. The first hint you're doing something wrong is the double `getNode()`. You're inserting ONE node, so that is a big red flag in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does several things incorrectly:

- You're allocating two nodes; not one (this isn't Java or C#).
- You don't account for the possibility that the *first* node in the list may already be "greater" than the incoming node.
- You don't wire the new node in correctly.

I have absolutely no idea how your comparison function works. the code seems to indicate it returns 1 so long as the list first value is "less" than the second (which would be exactly the opposite of how most comparators work. most do this:

- lhs < rhs  : return < 0
- lhs == rhs : return 0
- lhs > rhs  : return > 0

Be that as it may, I retrofitted your algorithm regardless.

```
STATUS insertInOrderList(LIST *list, const ELEMLIST *pElem) 
{

    NODE *newNode = getNode();
    newNode->data = *pElem;

    while (*list && cmpEleList(&(*list)->data, pElem) != 1)
        list = &(*list)->next;

    newNode->next = *list;
    *list = newNode; 

    return OK;
}
```

This assumes if the list is empty `*list` will be NULL, and that the allocation succeeded. Tailor to whatever you wish. Best of luck.

Comment: thanks, totally worked this way, anyway... I don't really see what you do in the condition of the while... you increase the list pointer?

Comment: @user3027143 Sorry. just saw your question. Remember, your `list` variable is a *pointer-to-pointer*. The conditional checks to see if (a) the pointer being pointed-to is non-null, and if so, drives through to the data member of the node pointed to by that pointer and compares it against `pElem`. So long as both are true, (there's a non-null node pointer, and the data it refers to is "less-than" the param), load `list` with the address of the `next` member of the current node. Basically it uses the actual pointers, not just their values, to walk through the list.